# Why does the creation of a child object creates a copy of the parent object?

Tags: python, oop, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In my Flask project, I'm trying to create executions of objects called 'seance', which inherit from a seance, and also link them so i can have a list of executions in my object seance, and the 'parent' seance in my object execution.
I also want to delete the executions of a seance if i delete the parent object.
With my code like this:

```
class SeanceModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'seances'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    titre = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)   # On ne met pas de contrainte d'unicité ici,
    # sinon on ne peut pas avoir plusieurs executions de la même seance(il faudrait chercher une solution)
    archiver = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    matiere = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    commentaire = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    image = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    type = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

    executions = db.relationship('ExecutionSeanceModel', back_populates='seance', cascade="all, delete")

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'seance',
        'polymorphic_on': type
    }
```

```
class ExecutionSeanceModel(SeanceModel):
    __tablename__ = 'executions_seances'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    etat = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    date_depart = db.Column(Date)
    date_fin = db.Column(Date)
    heure_depart = db.Column(Time)
    heure_fin = db.Column(Time)
    duree_heure = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    seance_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('seances.id'), nullable=False)

    seance = db.relationship('SeanceModel', back_populates='executions', foreign_keys=[seance_id])

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'execution_seance',
    }

    classes = db.relationship('ClasseModel', secondary='executions_seances_classes', back_populates='executions_seances')
```

```
class PlainExecutionSeanceSchema(PlainSeanceSchema):
    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    etat = fields.Str(required=True)
    date_depart = fields.Date()
    date_fin = fields.Date()
    heure_depart = fields.Time()
    heure_fin = fields.Time()
    duree_heure = fields.Integer()
    seance_id = fields.Integer()
    type = fields.Str()


class ExecutionSeanceSchema(PlainExecutionSeanceSchema):
    classes = fields.List(fields.Nested('PlainClasseSchema', dump_only=True))


class ExecutionSeanceUpdateSchema(SeanceSchema):
    etat = fields.Str()
    date_depart = fields.Date()
    date_fin = fields.Date()
    heure_depart = fields.Time()
    heure_fin = fields.Time()
    duree_heure = fields.Integer()
    id_seance = fields.Integer()
    type = fields.Str()
```

```
@blp.route("/exec_seance/<string:seance_id>")
class ExecutionOfASeance(MethodView):
    @blp.arguments(ExecutionSeanceSchema(partial=True))
    @blp.response(201, ExecutionSeanceSchema)
    def post(self, exec_seance_data, seance_id):

        seance = SeanceModel.query.get_or_404(seance_id)
        if seance:
            exec_seance = ExecutionSeanceModel()
            exec_seance.description = seance.description
            exec_seance.matiere = seance.matiere
            exec_seance.commentaire = seance.commentaire
            exec_seance.image = seance.image
            exec_seance.archiver = seance.archiver
            exec_seance.titre = seance.titre
            exec_seance.seance_id = seance.id
            exec_seance.duree_heure = exec_seance_data["duree_heure"]
            exec_seance.heure_depart = exec_seance_data["heure_depart"]
            exec_seance.heure_fin = exec_seance_data["heure_fin"]
            exec_seance.etat = exec_seance_data["etat"]
            exec_seance.date_depart = exec_seance_data["date_depart"]
            exec_seance.date_fin = exec_seance_data["date_fin"]
            exec_seance.type = exec_seance_data["type"]
        else:
            return abort(404, message="Seance not found.")

        # exec_seance = ExecutionSeanceModel(**exec_seance_data)   # A voir si on peut utiliser cette méthode

        db.session.add(exec_seance)
        db.session.commit()

        return exec_seance
```

Whenever i cretae an execution of a seance, it also cretaes a seance, which 'type' is 'execution_seance'.

I don't understand why it creates a copy of the parent object every time i create a child.

I tried to modify how the 2 tables are linked together, but it always create copies of the seance.

Comment: I don't think your table classes should be subclasses of each other. The foreign key expresses the relationship.

Comment: Thank you for our answer.
Indeed, the inheritance idea was  probably not the best way to do it, i created a "standalone" class execution) and linked it to the main classe.